# Immutable references in Swift

Tags: swift, class, constants, immutability

I'm learning Swift and I cannot find a way to achieve a C++ equivalent of a reference to `const`.

I'd like my object to be immutable instead of a immutable reference achieved by `let`.

Is there a way to have that in Swift?

Comment: When in Greece, do as the Greeks do. Don't try to find "equivalents". You are learning Swift, not trying to recreate everything you know about C++, in Swift.

Comment: How about a `struct` declared with `let`, with all its properties declared with `let` as well?

Comment: @Sweeper I find it perplexing that a function can unintentionally modify an object simply because it can. There's a reason for such feature in C++ and many other languages, as well as a good practice to use const wherever possible.

Comment: I understand your intention, which is why I suggested to use a struct with all its properties declared with `let`. This _is_ the Swifty way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in the comments, structs are the way to go with Swift if you want to ensure immutability. Regardless their properties are `let` or `var`, as long as the struct is passed by value (i.e. not `inout`), you are guaranteed that you won't be able to change the struct instance that was passed to your function. Even if you mutate it within your function, you'll only mutate a **copy**.

Now, back to C++, things can go horribly wrong even with `const` references, since you can easily bypass them. Take for example this code:

```cpp
struct Immutable {
public:
    int someIntValue = 9;
};

void doSomething(const Immutable &immutable) {
    //immutable->someIntValue = 10; // won't compile
    Immutable *mutableInstance = (Immutable *)&immutable;
    mutableInstance->someIntValue = 10;
}

int main() {
    Immutable immutable;
    printf("%d\n", immutable.someIntValue); // 9
    doSomething(immutable);
    printf("%d\n", immutable.someIntValue); // 10... hmm.. did my const reference just got mutated?
}
```

Clearly, the commented out line won't compile, as you'll be attempting to change a `const` reference, however as soon as you cast to a normal pointer you'll be able to alter the instance as you like.

Now, constructs like the above one are not possible in Swift, due to value vs. reference semantics. Struct's passed by reference are in no way alterable from the caller, unless the caller allows it (`inout`).

Conclusion: Swift has better mechanisms when it comes to readonly references, and these come in the form of value types. As long as you use value types you're guaranteed to have the control that you want. When you start circulating reference types... well... it's not much differences of what you have in C++.